# Does Rails recognize db view?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way that to access my db view as a table for a model?

Comment: Basically he/she wants to know if you can use a VIEW with ActiveRecord. i.e. `CREATE VIEW some_view AS SELECT * FROM tbl`. Because AR is reflective, it might not understand it.  DM (DataMapper) would handle it fine, as it doesn't try to be reflective.

Comment: I *think* he's asking if he can generate a model that instead of relying on a table, uses a db view (as opposed to an MVC/Rails view). To make sure I'm being clear (not didactic) a view generated with some sql and built into the db schema so it can be treated as a table in SQL interactions...

Comment: @jaydel you are right. that is exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use views just fine, they behave just like tables in ActiveRecord. I don't know what database you're using, but I use them in Oracle and haven't had a problem.

The only difference is that if you want to have your migrations automatically create them, you'll have to forego the typical create_table and instead execute SQL statements to create it.

Comment: i am using oracle as well but there is a problem when i write 'set_table_name :myview' in model and check it in my console it says 'The table doesn't exist'

Comment: @usmanali, you also have to grant the proper privileges for the view, or it acts like it doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you using the activerecord-oracle_enhanced driver?

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDb, I accessed to the MongoDB Views with the following method.

Firstly you should create a dummy model to be able to use MongoDB connectors. You can manually create new file with the name **view_names.rb** and append below lines.

```
class ViewName
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
end
```

And then to access records;

```
ViewName.collection.find({})
>> #<Mongo::Collection::View:0x0000000107cd4378>)
```

find gets MongoDB queries as parameter, so you can pass your logic as hash to find method.

```
{created_at: { '$lte': Date.todat - 2.week }}
```

View name on MongoDB should be plural **view_names** just as same with the others.